# select2 multiple field only with search

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a multiple select list `$("#myField").select2();` that works fine.
I get the values from the database and with a foreach loop i add all the options to the list.
I want to ask if there is any option that when a user clicks the field to select, to show no results, only the search field. The results must show after the user writes at least 1 character

Comment: I think https://api.jquery.com/blur/ will fill your requirement. If you post detail of your code, I can help with complete solution.

Comment: @Amit I think you misunderstood the question. I think the question is about not showing any options when the select element is clicked, but only propagate the options when the user has entered one or more characters in the search field that comes with a Select2 replacement element.

Comment: @Terry , yeah his english is very difficult to understand. Not getting to the point. I am not sure if he is asking something like autocomplete in select or something else

Comment: Select2 does not offer the possibility to hide `<option>` elements until a search is triggered. Also, what you are describing is actually somewhat of an **anti-pattern**: a select field should display all possible options, and the search filter serves to filter all options based on what the user has typed in.

Comment: Yes i mean autocomplete. Sorry for my english